# Updating a Field of record if it is found to be a duplicate

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have the following Mysql select that returns all the duplicate email addresses in my table.

```
SELECT users.FirstName, `Surname`, users.email1
FROM users
INNER JOIN (  
    SELECT email1   
  FROM users
GROUP BY email1   
HAVING count(email1) > 1) dup ON users.email1 = dup.email1   
ORDER BY users.email1
```

This works great, what I wish to do now is update a field called users.DupEmail with "YES" but I am unsure how to do this.  I have tried putting an update line to replace the select, but I am clearly getting it wrong as I am back here asking for help.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax with a self-join:

```
UPDATE users AS u1
  JOIN users AS u2 USING (email1)
   SET u1.DupEmail = 'YES'
 WHERE NOT u1.id = u2.id; -- use your primary key here
```

Comment: Thank you eggyal a quick response - tested and working, awesome

Answer (score 0):

The following script must solve your problem -- be safe and use the SELECT to test results before aplying the update:

```
-- SELECT FirstName, Surname, email1
-- FROM users

UPDATE users
SET DupEmail = 1
WHERE u0.email1 IN (
    SELECT u1.email1
    FROM users u1
    GROUP BY u1.email1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```